# How do I add section/subsection numbers to pdf bookmarks?

Tags: sectioning, hyperref, numbering, bookmarks

I'm writing up solutions to some exercises, and having problems with the bookmarks produced in the resulting pdf file. In the document I'm using `\section` (slightly modified) and `\exercise` (based on `\subsection`) - I'd like these to appear in the bookmarks in *exactly* the same way they appear in the document, including the numbering. Without the numbering, `\exercise` appears as a blank bookmark...

I know I could use the optional parameter for the `\section` and `\exercise` commands to manually specify the text used in the bookmarks, but I'd like to avoid it!

## Code - main file

```
\documentclass[answers]{exam}

\addtolength{\textwidth}{1cm}
\addtolength{\hoffset}{-0.5cm}
\addtolength{\textheight}{1cm}
\addtolength{\voffset}{-0.5cm}

\usepackage{xcolor} % Use colour!
\usepackage{titlesec} % Allow creation of new sectioning commands
\usepackage{amsmath} % Needed for splitting equations over multiple lines
\usepackage{ulem} % Underlining effects
\usepackage{environ} % Tinkering with environments
\usepackage{gensymb} % Degree symbol
\usepackage[pdfstartview=FitH,bookmarks=true]{hyperref} 
\usepackage{bookmark} %PDF Bookmarks

\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\large\bfseries}{Chapter }{0em}{\thesection: }

\titleclass{\exercise}{straight}[\section]  % Create new 'section' command for exercises - this replaces \subsection
\newcounter{exercise}
\titleformat{\exercise}{\normalfont\large\bfseries}{Exercise }{0em}{\theexercise}
\titlespacing*{\exercise}{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}
\newcommand{\exerciseautorefname}{exercise}
\makeatletter
\providecommand*{\toclevel@exercise}{2} % Make sure exercises appear below sections in bookmarks
\makeatother

\pagestyle{headandfoot} % Let's have both
\header{\oddeven{Exercise \theexercise}{Chapter \thesection: \rightmark}}{Core 1}{\oddeven{Chapter \thesection: \rightmark}{Exercise \theexercise}}
\headrule
\footer{\oddeven{}{\thepage}}{}{\oddeven{\thepage}{}}
\footrule

\renewcommand\sectionmark[1]{\markright{#1}} % Set up \rightmark

\begin{document}

\unframedsolutions % Print solutions as plain text
\SolutionEmphasis{\color{blue}} % Print solutions in blue
\renewcommand{\thepartno}{\roman{partno}} % Format part numbers as lower-case roman numerals
\renewcommand\theexercise{\thesection\Alph{exercise}} % Print exercise numbers as 1A, etc...
\renewcommand{\solutiontitle}{\noindent} % Format solution - just print solution as entered
\newcommand{\ans}[1]{\uuline{#1}} % Double underline final answer

\NewEnviron{sol}{ % Align solutions sensibly
    \begin{solution}
        $\begin{aligned}
            \BODY
        \end{aligned}$
    \end{solution}
}

\include{Chapter1}

\end{document}
```

## Code - Chapter1.tex

```
\section{Basic Algebra}

\exercise{}
Some text...
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Bookmark are numbered with option `numbered` of package `bookmark`:

```
\usepackage{bookmark}
\bookmarksetup{numbered}
```

Of without `bookmark` with `hyperref` only:

```
\hypersetup{bookmarksnumbered}
```

Adding prefixes `Chapter` and `Exercise` can be done via a trick:

```
\renewcommand*{\thesection}{%
  \texorpdfstring{}{Chapter }%
  \arabic{section}%
  \texorpdfstring{}{:}%
}

\renewcommand*{\theexercise}{%
  \texorpdfstring{}{Exercise }%
  \arabic{section}%
  \Alph{exercise}%
}
```

Comment: That adds the numbers (how did I miss that option!) - but it doesn't format them _exactly_ the same way as they are in the document. `\section` needs to be like `Chapter 1: Basic Algebra`; `\exercise` needs to be like `Exercise 1A`.

Comment: That's an improvement - it gives me the correct bookmark for the `\section` headings. However, the `\exercise` headings show up as `Chapter 1:A`, `Chapter 1:B`, etc.

Comment: @JustinT The old `\renewcommand{\theexercise}` needs to be replaced by the new version.

Comment: Nowadays also works with '\usepackage[bookmarksnumbered]{hyperref}'.