# How to change the PDFBookmark titles (hyperref)

Tags: hyperref, bookmarks

I am looking to change the title which displays in the PDF bookmark tabs to match the format of how I have my chapters listed.

```
\documentclass[]{report}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref} %to add hyperlinks throughout document
\usepackage{titlesec} %reformatting the chapter headings
\titleformat{\chapter}[block]
    {\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries\centering}{CHAPTER \thechapter}{0em}{:\hspace{2mm}}
\begin{document}

\chapter{THE BEGINNING}
Hello.

\chapter{THE END}
Goodbye.
\end{document}
```

What i currently have is:

[image: title format]

with the option of creating bookmarks of:

[image: bad bookmarks1]
[image: bad bookmarks2]

What I want my bookmarks to look like is identical to how the chapter title is formatted:

[image: good bookmark]

I have found that I can input `\pdfbookmark[0]{THE BEGINNING}{name1}`, but I would need to remove the bookmarks created by `hyperref` (which would not be ideal if I have multiple chapters, sections, subsections, etc., and have to input them all manually using this method.)

Will I have to work with changing `\chapter{THE BEGINNING}` to `\chapter{CHAPTER \thechapter: THE BEGINNING}`, then worry about removing the chapter number from 'CHAPTER 1: THE BEGINNING' from the title and ToC?

UPDATE:

The best option I found is:
[How to remove chapter numbering without removing it from tableofcontents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110840/how-to-remove-chapter-numbering-without-removing-it-from-tableofcontents)

I can use the code

```
\newcommand{\mychapter}[2]{
    \setcounter{chapter}{#1}
    \setcounter{section}{0}
    \chapter*{#2}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#2}}
```

I use TeXMaker, and I like the structure is provides for opening/organizing subfiles (i.e. using `\input{...}`).  To keep this as organized as possible, I resorted to the following:

1. Create `.tex` file titled `Chapter.1.THEBEGINNING`
2. This subfile will include `\mychapter{1}{CHAPTER \thechapter: THE BEGINNING}`
3. My main document will include `\input{Chapter.1.THEBEGINNING}`

This works well enough...although still looking for better options.

Comment: Maybe Heikos answer to this question will solve your problem: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/115008/how-do-i-add-section-subsection-numbers-to-pdf-bookmarks

Comment: Use `\hypersetup{bookmarksnumbered} \renewcommand*{\thechapter}{\texorpdfstring{}{CHAPTER }\arabic{chapter}\texorpdfstring{}{:}}`

Comment: You may want to update `\titleformat`, otherwise you'll see `:` before every `\chapter*`.

Comment: @Werner I have modified \chapter*{...} to \section*{\LARGE\bfseries\centering...} for this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This example provides a small modification of [Werner's solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/156553/16967). Instead of patching the internal `\Hy@writebookmark` the redefinition of `\numberline` is done in the bookmark hook `addtohook` of package `bookmark`:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\bookmarksetup{numbered}

\usepackage{titlesec} %reformatting the chapter headings
\titleformat{\chapter}[block]
  {\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries\centering}
  {CHAPTER\thechapter: }{0em}{}

\makeatletter
\bookmarksetup{%
  addtohook={%
    \ifnum\toclevel@chapter=\bookmarkget{level}\relax
      \renewcommand*{\numberline}[1]{CHAPTER #1: }%
    \fi
  },
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{THE BEGINNING}
Hello.
\section{A section}

\chapter{THE END}
Goodbye.
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 6):

You can insert a conditional to change the way `\numberline` functions when dealing with `\chapter`s:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyperref}{hidelinks}
\usepackage{bookmark,etoolbox}
\bookmarksetup{numbered}
\usepackage{titlesec} %reformatting the chapter headings
\titleformat{\chapter}[block]
  {\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries\centering}{CHAPTER \thechapter:\hspace{2mm}}{0em}{}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\Hy@writebookmark}% <cmd>
  {\let\chapternumberline\Hy@numberline}% <search>
  {\ifx\Hy@toclevel\toclevel@chapter\def\numberline##1{CHAPTER ##1: }\fi}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{THE BEGINNING}
Hello.
\section{A section}

\chapter{THE END}
Goodbye.
\end{document}
```

The default of `\numberline` (similarly `\Hy@numberline` used by [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) is to set the number followed by a space:

```
\def\numberline#1{#1 }
```

I've just patched `\Hy@writebookmark` to correct `\numberline` when you're dealing with a `\chapter` using the conditional `\ifx\Hy@toclevel\toclevel@chapter`. The patch requires [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox). It can be updated to provide different prefixes for different sectional units/headings.