# Section numbers in PDF bookmarks

Tags: pdf, bookmarks

I need to write section numbers in PDF bookmarks, but only for section (and not for subsections etc.). Desired result:

[image]

Now I use `bookmark` package, so I can write numbers for every bookmark with *numbered* option. It is possible, to show numbers only for top-level bookmarks? (Another-leveled items like subsections and deeper must be showed in bookmarks, but without numbers)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage[
  open,
  openlevel=2,
  atend,
  numbered
]{bookmark}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\Hy@numberline}[1]{#1. }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{Bla bla}
...
\subsection{Lorem}
...
\subsection{ipsum}
..
\section{Bla bla bla}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry, but your question is a little bit unclear

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/115008

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Option `addtohook` of package `bookmark` allows to change the settings for a bookmark in dependence of some parameters such as the bookmark level.
Thus the following would solve the problem:

```
\bookmarksetup{
  numbered,
  addtohook={%
    \ifnum\bookmarkget{level}>1 %
      \bookmarksetup{numbered=false}%
    \fi
  },
}
```

Unhappily option `numbered` is evaluated *before* the hook in `\bookmark` is executed, see the definition of `\Hy@writebookmark` in package `bookmark`.
Thus the following example changes the effect of option `numbered` instead:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage[atend]{bookmark}

\bookmarksetup{
  open,
  openlevel=2,
  numbered,
  addtohook={%
    \ifnum\bookmarkget{level}>1 %
      \DisableBookmarkNumbering
    \fi
  },
}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\DisableBookmarkNumbering}{%
  \let\numberline\@gobble
  % The followings are not needed for subsections and below
  % \let\booknumberline\@gobble
  % \let\partnumberline\@gobble
  % \let\chapternumberline\@gobble
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{Bla bla}
...
\subsection{Lorem}
...
\subsection{ipsum}
..
\section{Bla bla bla}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 8):

You can use the following switches:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
  open,
  openlevel=2,
  atend,
  numbered
]{bookmark}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\numbersections}{\renewcommand{\Hy@numberline}[1]{##1. }}
\newcommand{\nonumbersections}{\renewcommand{\Hy@numberline}[1]{}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\numbersections
\section{Bla bla}
...

\nonumbersections
\subsection{Lorem}
...

\subsection{ipsum}
..

\numbersections
\section{Bla bla bla}
\end{document}
```

`\numbersections` turns on numbering in the bookmarks, while `\nonumbersections` turns it off.

---

The above process can be automated by adding the following to your preamble:

```
\let\oldsection\section
\renewcommand{\section}{\numbersections\oldsection}
\let\oldsubsection\subsection
\renewcommand{\subsection}{\nonumbersections\oldsubsection}
```

It inserts the required switch before using `\section` or `\subsection`. Of course it's not needed for `\subsubsection`, as they would necessarily fall under `\subsection` (where bookmark numbering has been deactivated via `\nonumbersections`) and it would seem strange to have a `\subsubsection` without `\subsection`.

Answer (score 3):

Some surgery on kernel macros; I redefine `\@sect` to write `\xnumberline{<level>}` instead of `\numberline`, but defining `\xnumberline` to ignore its first argument and execute `\numberline`.

I also patch `\Hy@writebookmark` to redefine `\xnumberline` so that `\xnumberline{<level>}` becomes `\stas@numberline@<level>`; such commands are then defined to do what we prefer: `\stas@numberline@section` prints the number followed by a period and a space, while `\stas@numberline@subsection` just ignores the number.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage[
  open,
  openlevel=2,
  atend,
  numbered
]{bookmark}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\H@old@sect} % \@sect becomes \H@old@sect
  {\numberline}
  {\xnumberline{#1}}
  {}{}
\def\xnumberline#1{\numberline} % for the TOC
\patchcmd{\Hy@writebookmark}
  {\let\numberline}
  {\let\xnumberline\stas@numberline\let\numberline}
  {}{}
\patchcmd{\Hy@writebookmark}
  {\else\let\numberline}
  {\else\let\xnumberline\@gobbletwo\let\numberline}
  {}{}

\def\stas@numberline#1{\csname stas@numberline@#1\endcsname}
\def\stas@numberline@section#1{#1. }
\let\stas@numberline@subsection\@gobble
\let\stas@numberline@subsubsection\@gobble
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{Bla bla}
...
\subsection{Lorem}
...
\subsection{ipsum}
..
\section{Bla bla bla}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: IMHO this is an ugly hack.

Comment: @MartinSchröder I don't agree. It gives much more structure than a simple `\numberline` in the `.toc` entries, so one gets more freedom in typesetting the numbers.